# how to get elements with no class name in javascript

Tags: javascript, scripting, getelementsbyclassname

I want to extract text from span elements with no class name. How can it be done?
Elements with particular class name can be searched but how to get only the elements with no class name for them?

```
<span>0m2abBrL+RIHOEA+dZS+OqV3St+nJ/</span>
<wbr></wbr>
<span class="word_break"></span>
<span>zwq73Gfz8MQGB0yS++lfufSOV133huE</span>
<wbr></wbr>
<span class="word_break"></span>
vCB0s5D9w
<span class="text_exposed_hide">...</span>
```

Comment: do you want this in pure javascript or jquery could be an option?

Comment: Hi, I added code in java script also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate through them and check the classname I suppose.

```
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    if (spans[i].className == '') {
        //span doesn't have a class
    }
}
```

Comment: It would also suit to have a `querySelectorAll` fork as most modern browsers support it and it should be faster than a for loop where available.

Answer (score 1):

more optimization could be done.. but this is how you can do this..

```
 function getElementsByNoClassName() {
            var node = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
            var a = [];
            var els = node.getElementsByTagName("*");
            for (var i = 0, j = els.length; i < j; i++)
                if (els[i].className=='') a.push(els[i]);
            return a;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite how annoying I find it, I'll give a jQuery answer (since mrtsherman beat me to the punch with a *real* answer):

```
$('span:not([class])')
```

Comment: No jQuery tag on the post and a comment by the OP before your answer that says they want plain javascript.

Comment: Sorry; didn't see the comment.

Comment: You should refrain from jQuery answers if the OP doesn't ask for jQuery - either by explicitly mentioning jQuery or if the post is tagged with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

With [`Element.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll), you could use the following code to achieve that.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('span').querySelectorAll('span:not([class])');
```

Answer (score -1):

After  downvote of my friend I have added code in core java script here:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
span{display:block;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getElementsByNoClassName() {
            var node = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
            console.log(node.length);
            var a = [];         
            for (var i = 0, j = node.length; i < j; i++){
                   if (node[i].className=='') 
                    node[i].setAttribute("style","color:red;");            
                  }
 }

window.onload=getElementsByNoClassName;
</script>
</head>
<body>
Content with No class is colored in red.
<span>0m2abBrL+RIHOEA+dZS+OqV3St+nJ/</span>
<wbr></wbr>
<span class="word_break"></span>
<span>zwq73Gfz8MQGB0yS++lfufSOV133huE</span>
<wbr></wbr>
<span class="word_break"></span>
vCB0s5D9w
<span class="text_exposed_hide">...</span>
</body>
</html>
```

This can be done with jQuery also:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
span{display:block;}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$("span").filter(
      function(){
         return $(this).attr('class')==undefined
       }).css('color','red');
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
Content with No class is colored in red.
<span>0m2abBrL+RIHOEA+dZS+OqV3St+nJ/</span>
<wbr></wbr>
<span class="word_break"></span>
<span>zwq73Gfz8MQGB0yS++lfufSOV133huE</span>
<wbr></wbr>
<span class="word_break"></span>
vCB0s5D9w
<span class="text_exposed_hide">...</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No jQuery tag on the post and a comment by the OP before your answer that says they want plain javascript.

Comment: Your plain javascript version doesn't do what the OP asked.

Comment: It appears to work now, but `if (!node[i].className)` would be safer than comparing to `""` because it will handled `undefined`, `null` and `""`.

Comment: And, what's the `var a = []` for?  Looks like it was copied from one of the other answers.

Comment: yes :) from Shoaib's answer. can you remove the downvote please ?